# How to display the SQL select content in ruby ​script?

Tags: ruby

I'm using Ruby to create a test script connecting to oracle BD.

I have all the structure already set up, I can already connect and search the database.

Is there any way for me to display the SELECT content? Using only RUBY, I don't use Ruby on Rails.

Comment: _"Using only RUBY"_ – how do you send the `SELECT` query to the database?

Comment: @WilliansSilveira : You forgot to show your Ruby program in your post. I can't see how you connect to the database.